# addClass and removeClass in Jquery on radio button select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, checked

I have 2 different sets of radio buttons. But radio buttons are being displayed as an images. My question is on the select of picture (radio button), I would like other pictures to become hidden. So the way I thought is to add class to checked and than add another class to not checked. Base on the class on the not checked, i can hide those.

My problem is because I have 2 sets of radio buttons one for size and one for reason, I want them to differentiate them.So when I select size, I don't want all reasons radio buttons to become hidden.

So I can differentiate them separately and target them.

If I add this line of code:

```
$('label:has(input:radio:checked)').addClass('activeReason');
```

It apply to all radio buttons **which I don't want.**

Here is my radio buttons: **Size**

```
    <form id="sign-condition">

          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="sign-condition"  class="sign-condition" value="new_sign" />
            <img src="../../css/icons/new-signs.png">
          </label>

          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="sign-condition" class="sign-condition"  value="old_sign"/>
            <img src="../../css/icons/old-signs.png">
          </label>
    </form>
```

Here is my radio buttons: **Reasons**

```
    <div class="col-md-6">

                <form id="sign-reason">

                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sign-reason" value="damaged" />
                    <img src="../../css/buttons/damaged.png">
                  </label>

                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sign-reason" value="odd-size"/>
                    <img src="../../css/buttons/odd-size.png">
                  </label>

                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="sign-reason" value="not-correct-standard"/>
                    <img src="../../css/buttons/not-correct-standard.png">
                  </label>
     </form
```

Here is JQuery which I tried to target each set differently.

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){ 

        $('input:radio').click(function() {
            $('label>.sign-condition:has(input:radio:checked)').addClass('activeCondition');
            $('label>.sign-condition:has(input:radio:checked)').removeClass('disable');
            $('label>.sign-condition:has(input:radio:not(:checked))').removeClass('activeCondition');
            $('label>.sign-condition:has(input:radio:not(:checked))').addClass('disable');

        });



        });
        </script>
```

**How I can target each set of radio buttons differently. Thank you**

Comment: Probably easiest if you go up to the form element first (`.parents()`), and then use that to either `find` the labels under that element only, or pass it in as a _context_.

Comment: Do you want to perform action on same radio button OR other set radio button? by your code I can see you are performing operation on same radio only

Comment: What I would like user to do is select size and reason. When he select size, other size option should disappear and when select reasons, other reason should disappear.

Comment: question: if the user click an option and all others will disappear .. what if the user changes his mind and what to select another option?

Comment: @Amani, I best add like a toggle functionality. So clicking would hide the options and clicking again wouldshow option again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this what you need:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
       /*get the parent node of the radio and then hide only its siblings*/
       $(this).parent('label').siblings().toggle();
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sign-condition">

          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="sign-condition"  class="sign-condition" value="new_sign" />
            <img src="../../css/icons/new-signs.png">
          </label>

          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="sign-condition" class="sign-condition"  value="old_sign"/>
            <img src="../../css/icons/old-signs.png">
          </label>
    </form>
    
       <form id="sign-reason">

                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="sign-reason" value="damaged" />
                    <img src="../../css/buttons/damaged.png">
                  </label>

                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="sign-reason" value="odd-size"/>
                    <img src="../../css/buttons/odd-size.png">
                  </label>

                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="sign-reason" value="not-correct-standard"/>
                    <img src="../../css/buttons/not-correct-standard.png">
                  </label>
     </form>
```

Comment: That's amazing @Amani. Thank you so much. Just last question; clicking radio button would hide it's siblings, how about if I want to add toggle() so clicking would hide siblings and clicking again would show the option again. Would toggle() work.

Comment: `$(this).parent('label').siblings().toggle();` I tried that but it didn't worked.

Comment: then u need to use checkbox not radios

Comment: I updated the answer ..if you keep using radio... after selecting one option and hiding all the other one you cannot un-select it again since you have to select an option.

Answer (score 0):

Try below JS code. replace it with your code temporary.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(#sign-condition input:radio).click(function() {
            $('label>.sign-condition:has(input:radio:not(:checked))').removeClass('activeCondition').addClass('disable');
            $(this).removeClass('disable').addClass('activeCondition');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I just seen your last comment reply. so for reason and condition you need different identifier again. which can be your form name so prepend form name for radio click event

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByName should return the arrays by the names you have for the radio buttons. Then on that result, use your logic to addClass on checked button.

Answer (score -1):

Get the name and value of currently clicked radio button, then get the radio buttons by name (Native javascript or jQuery), it will be an array, traverse the the array by using the best method which you know, and hide the radio button where value is not equal to currently clicked radio button.

Hope it helps.